# I am trying to learn uses of GUI but vscode and eclipse are both saying "GUI cannot be resolved to a type" after declaring "new GUI()" in main

Tags: user-interface, compiler-errors, typeerror, java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUITest {
    private JPasswordField passwordBox;
    private JButton enterButton = new JButton ("Enter");
    private JLabel textBox = new JLabel("Enter Password Here:");;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public void GUITest() {
        PanelSetup();
        FrameSetup();
    }
    
    public void PanelSetup(){
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(150, 150, 250, 250));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    }

    public void FrameSetup(){
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("GUI TEST");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new GUI();

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the problem is creating the new GUI and I cannot run the code to see if the rest of it works and/or adding more stuff to it. If you can help that would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you havea class called GUI in your project?

Comment: I hadn't but i got it fixed didn't realize the GUI was based on the class name

Answer (score 1):

Change "new GUI();" to "new GUITest();" as you are creating a new instance of the current class.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    new GUI();

}
```

to

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    new GUITest();
}
```

Also, remove the void tag from your constructor as it turns it into a method.

```
public void GUITest() {
    PanelSetup();
    FrameSetup();
}
```

to

```
public GUITest() {
    PanelSetup();
    FrameSetup();
}
```

It seems like you're new to java, welcome! I'd take a look at w3schools excellent java docs if you want to get better at syntax. [w3schools java](https://www.w3schools.com/java/default.asp)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know i got kind of confused by that. I am not very new I'm just trying to learn GUI but I was having problems. Just learning as I go along to be honest :)

Comment: Glad to help. :)